# Cherrypy HTTP server

Tags: python, http, cherrypy

I'm implementing a python application that can handle special set of operations which helps me to update the state of remote computers that I need to be alert. I'm trying to use [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) HTTP framework for the implementation.

Following shows a code, that I used to practice the framework (I followed a tutorial). but it is not working properly. Even though it mean to give a text area that I can run and test an python code, it is not even prompt the text box.Since it is not generating any error i cannot find the problem please help me.

```
import cherrypy
import os
from tempfile import gettempdir
TMP_DIR = gettempdir()

class Pycompiler(object):
title = 'Play with Python'

def header(self):
    return '''
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>%s</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h2>%s</h2>
        ''' % (self.title, self.title)

def footer(self):
    return '''
            </body>
            </html>
        '''  

    def index(self, code=None):
    cherrypy.session['code'] = code
    output = ''
    if code is None:
        cherrypy.session['output'] = 'hello'
    else:
        tmp_filename = os.path.join(TMP_DIR, 'my_file.dat')
        f = open(tmp_filename, 'w')
        f.write(code)
        f.close()
        f_in, f_out = os.popen4("python %s"%tmp_filename)
        output = "The result of"
        output += "<pre><font color='blue'>%s</font></pre>is: "%code
        output += "<pre><font color='green'>"
        for line in f_out.readlines():
            output += line
        output += "</font></pre>"
        cherrypy.session['output'] = output        
    return self.header()+'''
            <form action="index" method="GET">
            <textarea name="code" rows=10 cols=160></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Run Code"/>
            </form>
            <br/>
            %s
        ''' % output + self.footer()
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.root = Pycompiler()
cherrypy.config.update({'session_filter.on': True})

if __name__ == '__main__':
cherrypy.config.update('configuration.conf')#Neet have a file 
cherrypy.server.start()
```

Comment: Is the indenting correct in your code? Its not correct in the snippet you pasted. What is the output you get when you run this file?

Comment: No indentation is not the problem. there are some mistakes during I past the code here wait ill correct them thanks a lot :)